# Define function that interleaves and then evaluates its arguments

Tags: evaluation, hold

I wish to define a function `interleaveWithX[statements__]` with behavior such that evaluating, for example,

```
interleaveWithX[a, b, c, d]
```

produces the same results as evaluating

```
a; x; b; x; c; x; d
```

Getting the arguments interwoven is no problem; something like

```
interleaveWithX[statements__] := Riffle[List@statements, x]
```

does the job fine. But assuming that the `statements` and `x` are already defined, I'm struggling to figure out what combination of `SetAttribute`, `Hold`, `Unevaluated`, `ReleaseHold`, `Evaluate`, etc. I need to incorporate in my function definition, and where, in order to delay evaluation of the arguments until I've interwoven them into the desired order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does the job. Probably not in the most elegant way:

```
ClearAll[interleaveWithX];
SetAttributes[interleaveWithX, HoldAll];
interleaveWithX[statements__] := 
 With[{list = Riffle[{Hold /@ Unevaluated[statements]}, x]},
  CompoundExpression @@@ HoldComplete[list] /. Hold[y_] :> y
  ]

interleaveWithX[1+1, b, c, d]
```

> HoldComplete[1 + 1; x; b; x; c; x; d]

The `HoldComplete` is there to show you the unevaluated output. The final function would be wrapped with `ReleaseHold`:

```
ClearAll[interleaveWithX];
SetAttributes[interleaveWithX, HoldAll];
interleaveWithX[statements__] := 
 ReleaseHold @ With[{list = Riffle[{Hold /@ Unevaluated[statements]}, x]},
  CompoundExpression @@@ HoldComplete[list] /. Hold[y_] :> y
  ]
```

Comment: I had to use `Hold @ x` instead of `x` since I also want `x` to remain unevaluated prior to riffling, but other than that this does the job! Apart from the evaluation stuff, `CompoundExpression` is very helpful to know about, thanks!